# Регулярные выражения: захватить все повторы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

приветствую!

есть простое регулярное выражение

```
/\[([^\s]+)(?:\s([^\s]+))+\]/g
```

и возьмем какой-нить текст

```
dsdsklfjdf [one two three]  xdkxclkffd dsdsklfjdf [one two three four]  xdkxclkffd
```

В первом случае захватываются one и three, во втором - one и four. То есть,  группой повтора захватывается только последнее значение. А можно захватить все повторы просто регуляркой без кода (с кодом решений предлагать не надо, и сам explode поставить могу - это просто сильно упрощенный вариант, чтоб проблему показать)?

[вот тут можно поковырять :)](https://www.regex101.com/r/uA6uX1/1)

Comment: Может, такое подойдет: [`(?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*([^\s\]]+)(?=[^]]*\])`](https://www.regex101.com/r/eD4wZ6/1)? Тут, правда, не видно отдельных блоков.

Comment: почему же нге видно, отлично все получилось. пишите ответ

Comment: самый простой вариант увидеть разделение блоков - https://www.regex101.com/r/uA6uX1/2

Comment: `[one two three]` и `[one] [two, three]` должны быть обработаны по-разному или нет разницы и важны только слова внутри скобок?

Comment: по разному. каждый блок отдельно

Comment: В таком случае используйте хороший и всем понятный паттерн «каскадный спуск», когда сначала выделяется некая общая сущность, а внутри нее уже выделяются более мелкие сущности. Можно конечно сделать флаг, что раз найдена открывающая скобка, то началась первая группа слов и все захваченные слова принадлежат ей, пока не встретится другая открывающая скобка. Я просто не советовал решать Ваши реальные задачи таким кодом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если есть задача найти совпадения внутри какого-то размеченного блока, можно воспользоваться оператором `\G` (найти совпадения только после удачного предыдущего).

```
(?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*([^\s\]]+)(?=[^]]*\])
```

[Демо](https://www.regex101.com/r/eD4wZ6/1)

`(?:\[|(?!^)\G)` находит начало блока - `[`, а затем ищет разделенные пробелом подстроки, состоящие из отличных от пробела и закрывающей скобки символов (`\s*([^\s\]]+)`). `(?=[^]]*\])` проверяет текущую позицию внутри скобок.

Если первую подмаску сделать захватывающей, можно заметить начало блока из квадратных скобок:

```
(\[|(?!^)\G)\s*([^\s\]]+)(?=[^]]*\])
```

[Демо 2](https://www.regex101.com/r/eD4wZ6/2)

Comment: Честно говоря даже не предлагал такой вариант, потому что полученные значения «оторваны» от своего контекста. Текст предполагает, что `[one two three]` будет обработан как одна сущность далее в коде, но Вашим выражением к сожалению нельзя установить, что one, two, three должны обрабатываться как одна группа слов без лишнего геммороя. Оптимальным будет так называемый «каскадный спуск».  `[one two three]` , `[one] [two, three]` как мне кажется, должны быть обработаны по-разному, что не позволяет Ваше выражение без дополнительных ухищрений.

Comment: @ReinRaus Я то же самое написал в комментарии. Но раз уж ТС понравилось, решил написать ответ.

Comment: Да мне интересно кто минус поставил :-) Хочется объяснить ему, что и как :-)

Comment: Я не знаю, по-моему, Ваш ответ пригодится всем, кто не хочет мучится со "сложными" регулярками.

Comment: @ReinRaus мне, конечно же, больше бы понравилось сразу получить правильный массив, но сейчас есть признак у первой захваченной группы блока, что дает возможность обработать достаточно просто

Comment: @ReinRaus на самом для меня это ответ. Потому, что  делить надо в реальной задаче не по explodde по preg_split с весьма сложными условиями. Поэтому меня интересовало, как захватить все повторы и ответ на это я получил. Просто я про эти заглядывалки вперед/назад не очень умею и все время забываю :)

Comment: Тут скорее дело не в сложности регулярного выражения, а в излишестве сопутствующего кода, который должен будет однозначно идентифицировать, что слово принадлежит именно этой группе слов, а не другой.

Comment: @ReinRaus ну уж ладно - две строки кода, которые разделят массив по  квадратной скобке в 0 индексе :)

Comment: @splash58 ничего не имею против :-) Просто рекомендую более хорошие практики написания кода.

Comment: @ReinRaus так, к обсуждению. почему вы называете этот код сложным :) https://eval.in/429170

Comment: @splash58 делайте как считаете правильным, я предложил Вам то, что сам считаю правильным. Минусы Вашего подхода: 1. Неочевидность что группа слов это единое целое 2. Вы «не очень» знаете все заглядывалки с Ваших слов 3. А если надо изменить что-то 4. А если другой человек будет пытаться изменить этот код- все ли в нем очевидно?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы используя регулярные выражения получить в данной ситуации каждое слово в отдельной группе нужно использовать «каскадный спуск».
Что это значит:
Сперва находите все, что попадает под регулярное выражение:

```
/\[[^\]]+\]/
```

То есть захватывается сразу `[one two three]` целиком.

```
preg_match_all( "/\\[[^\\]]+\\]/", $text, $arr);
```

Далее в цикле перебираются все полученные значения и к ним применяется более простое выражение:

```
/\S+/
```

---

Если количество слов внутри скобок ограничено, то можно сделать кучу сохраняющих групп.

---

Раз уж речь зашла об очевидности:

```
preg_match_all( "/\\[[^\\]]+\\]/", $text, $arr);
foreach( $arr as $k=>$v) {
    preg_match_all( "/\\S+/", $v, $arr2);
    myFunc( $arr2[0] );
}
```

Сравним с таким кодом:

```
//где-то здесь еще должно фигурировать регулярное выражение
//  (?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*([^\s\]]+)(?=[^]]*\])
$ar = [ ['[', 1], ['',2], ['[', 3], ['',4]];

$c = -1;
$new = array_reduce($ar, 
                function($n, $i) use (&$c) {
                   if($i[0] === '[') $c++;
                   $n[$c][] = $i[1];
                   return $n; },
                   []);
print_r($new);
```

Все. Ответ на простой вопрос перерос в флуд. За сим предлагаю это прекратить.

Comment: Прокомментируйте минус, пожалуйста :-) Раз Вы считаете иначе :-)

Comment: не я ставил, но я в вопросе прямо написал, что вариант с explode предлагать не надо :) возможно, поэтому вас заминусовали