# Регулярка. Неопределенное количество элементов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Товарищи коллеги! Подскажите кто шарит - есть строка `"байты: [ 53 30 45 00 45 00 0B C0 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 DB A1 18 ]  "`. Нужно выбрать массив значений в квадратных скобках `['53', '30' '45', '00', ...]`. Можно ли сделать это регуляркой без дополнительных манипуляций типа `split`? Количество значений в квадратных скобках может быть любым.

Составил вот такую регулярку `\[\ (([\dA-F]{2}\ )*)\]`, но она не дробит значения, а выбирает только подстроку в квадтарных скобка. Можно конечно её прогнать через `split` - но хотелось бы знать можно ли это сделать именно регуляркой.

Comment: а если так `[\dA-F]{2}` - https://regex101.com/r/3i3vtK/1

Comment: @splash58, это работает, но ругулярка дожна захватывать только значения в квадратыных скобках, чтоб по бокам были `[    ]` - это важное условие

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448577/Регулярные-выражения-захватить-все-повторы

Comment: Попробуйте `s.match(/\b[a-f0-9]{2}\b(?=[^\][]*])/ig)`.

Comment: Решение в [Регулярные выражения: захватить все повторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900720) заточено под PHP, чтобы его использовать для данной задачи непросто по нескольким причинам: 1) различие в экранировании квадратной закрывающей скобки в символьном классе, 2) само выражение в PHP более комплексное, нужно догадаться, что в JavaScript убрать, а что оставить, что не очевидно в ответе. В PHP решение, конечно, более точное, да и поддержку вложенных скобок легко реализовать. Дубликат, но с натяжкой, всё-таки эти решения для разных языков и не претендуют на универсальность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чаще всего в таких случаях количество скобок в строке "сбалансированное", т.е. для каждой открывающей скобки есть соответствующая закрывающая скобка. Если вложенных скобок нет, можно воспользоваться известным трюком: найти все совпадения, сразу после которых есть 0 и более символов, отличных от `]` и `[`, после которых идёт `]`.

```
s.match(/[a-f0-9]{2}(?=[^\][]*])/ig)
```

или

```
s.match(/\b[a-f0-9]{2}\b(?=[^\][]*])/ig)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/RbJANZ/1).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `[a-f0-9]{2}` - две буквы от `a` до `f` или цифры
- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?=[^\][]*])` - сразу справа от текущей позиции должны находиться 0 и более символов, отличных от `]` и `[`, а потом `]`
- `i` - регистронезависимый поиск
- `g` - поиск всех совпадений.

Comment: Класс, то что доктор прописал! Низкий вам поклон!

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов

```js
const reg = /([0-9A-F]{2})/g;
const str = 'байты: [ 53 30 45 00 45 00 0B C0 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 0A 01 DB A1 18 ]';

console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Comment: это работает, но нужно ругулярка дожна захватывать только значения в квадратыных скобках, чтоб по бокам были `[    ]` - это важное условие

Comment: @carcinogen75, то есть вам нужно извлечь подстроку - то, что заключено в квадратные скобки, - из строки или все же формировать массив значений из данной строки?

Comment: @gregzakharov Да, вот к примеру есть строка `байты: [ 53 30 45 00 ] а тут еще 44 AB 00 33` - вот надо чтоб на выходе получился только массив `["53", "30", "45", "00"]`

Comment: @carcinogen75, собственно, пример выше как раз и формирует массив значений.

Comment: @gregzakharov символы `44 AB 00 33` те что без квадратных скобок - не должны попасть в ответ. Я так понял, что тут надо использовать каскадный подход, одной регуляркой тут никак

Comment: @carcinogen75, а откуда эти символы берутся - те, что не должны попасть в результат? В вашем вопросе об этом ни слова. Может стоит подумать о том, чтобы перефразировать вопрос, чтобы вас наконец начали понимать?

Comment: @gregzakharov я вам пример выше привел `байты: [ 53 30 45 00 ] а тут еще 44 AB 00 33` (см. всю выделенную строку). В вопросе тоже четко написано "выбрать массив значений в *квадратных скобках*"

Comment: @carcinogen75, спорить с вами не собираюсь, но четкой формулировки вопроса, о которой вы говорите, в вашем вопросе нет, тем паче что сперва вам требуется `["53", "30", "45", "00"]`, после `[ 53 30 45 00 ]`, а `44 AB 00 33` в приведенной в вопросе последовательности не наблюдается в упор. Поэтому, будьте добры, не сочтите за труд, но сформулируйте свой вопрос четко от и до, чтобы не было двоякого толкования.